# How to display a progress indicator in Server Component while it wraps a Client Component ; NextJS 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I have a Server Component called `FormLayout` which wraps a client component `BuildingInfoForm`:

```
import styles from "./style.module.css"
import { BuildingInfoForm } from ".."

export const FormLayout = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(
    `my_api`,
    {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Key": `key`,
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
    }
  )
  const data = await res.json()

  return data ? (
    <div className={styles["layout"]}>
      <BuildingInfoForm data={data} />
    </div>
  ) : (
    <h1>Loading ...</h1>{**It does not displayed**}
  )
}
```

I want to display a progress indicator while the data is coming from the server.

I tried it in the `Form Layout` but it does not work.

Also, I tried it in the `BuildingInforForm` which is a client component but I could not see the indicator (  `<h1> Loading ...</h1>`):

```
 {data ? 
        <Form>
          ....
    </Form> : <h1>Loading </h1>
```

The loading does not appear in both cases though the API request works well.

Comment: That wont work. Your server component is rendered in the server before reaching client. At that moment, `data` contains the response from the api. Meaning no `loading` indicator.

Comment: Should I use `Suspence` ?

Comment: Nope. If you need to show a progress bar, you need to use a client component. When you are using server component, the client gets the page only after server received the full fetch response from `my_api`.

Comment: But NextJS recommend this [Loading State](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming#instant-loading-states)